# Is there a definitieve resource that documents navigation of the linux /proc and /sys filesystems?

Tags: linux, configuration, usb, pci-bus, scsi

We use the /proc and /sys file systems in Linux to discover various types of system configuration information.  Typically, we spelunk around through the different files and directories until we find the information that we need.

I'm wondering if anyone knows of a definitive resource that documents how one would navigate through the /proc and /sys file systems to locate specific information. We primarily grab USB, PCI and SCSI information from various files in these file systems.

Thanks,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The definitive resource for `/sys` is [Documentation/sysfs-rules.txt](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux-2.6.git;a=blob;f=Documentation/sysfs-rules.txt). The definitive resource for `/proc/sys` is [Documentation/sysctl/](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux-2.6.git;a=tree;f=Documentation/sysctl). The definitive resource for the rest of `/proc` appears to be [Documentation/filesystems/proc.txt](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux-2.6.git;a=blob;f=Documentation/filesystems/proc.txt). The rest of the `Documentation/` directory in the Linux kernel source has other interesting information. In particular, [Documentation/ABI/](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux-2.6.git;a=tree;f=Documentation/ABI) mentions the stability of each interface.

Comment: In short, all linux documentation is in Documentation/. :)

Comment: @presario: not all, part of it (mostly the system calls) can be found at http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/